# Not getting the correct output with this R script

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have once again thrown myself into learning R. However, I'm not sure if my data is formatted wrong or if I'm missing a key point.

The vision is to compare all samples against each other over time. However, nailing the code has proved difficult. I can't seem to get time on the x-axis and the samples to match and overlap. I have looked at what feels like 100 videos and web pages. Still can't work this in.

Script:

```
Data2 <- Data3 %>%
        gather( key = "test", value = "value", c(-Name))
  
Data2 %>%
  
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=value, y=test)) +
  ylab("Film type") +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  xlab("Time")
  


Name = c("2% No wash No cure 20gm", "3 % no wash no cure 20 gm",    "4 % no wash no cure 20 gm",    "2 % no cure just wash 20 gm",  "3 % no cure just wash 20gm",   "4 % no cure just wash 20 gm",  "3 % cure + wash 20 gm", "4%cure+wash 20gm")
```

Data:

```
structure(list(Name = c(0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 
135, 150, 165, 180), `2% No wash No cure 20gm` = c(0.0499999999999998, 
0.0800000000000001, 0.13, 0.23, 0.56, 0.61, 0.54, 0.54, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), `3 % no wash no cure 20 gm` = c(0.0200000000000005, 
0.04, 0.0700000000000003, 0.350000000000001, 0.42, 0.36, 0.36, 
0.350000000000001, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `4 % no wash no cure 20 gm` = c(0.0499999999999998, 
0.0899999999999999, 0.12, 0.18, 0.655, 0.649999999999999, 0.62, 
0.62, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2 % no cure just wash 20 gm` = c(0.04, 
0.0699999999999994, 0.0899999999999999, 0.13, 0.44, 0.64, 0.62, 
0.739999999999999, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `3 % no cure just wash 20gm` = c(0.04, 
0.0999999999999996, 0.0800000000000001, 0.0999999999999996, 0.23, 
0.6, 0.919999999999999, 1.42, 1.51, 1.64, NA, NA, NA), `4 % no cure just wash 20 gm` = c(0.0499999999999998, 
0.0899999999999999, 0.0999999999999996, 0.12, 0.13, 0.13, 0.2, 
0.37, 0.62, 0.86, 1.05, 1.23, 0.899999999999999), `3 % cure + wash 20 gm` = c(0.11, 
0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2, 0.37, 0.819999999999999, 1.34, 1.62, 
1.62, 2.02, 1.53), `4%cure+wash 20gm` = c(0.0600000000000005, 
0.11, 0.14, 0.16, 0.17, 0.19, 0.26, 0.680000000000001, 0.87, 
1.02, 1.12, 1.29, 1.12)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: OP, please share your data in a format that is reproducible.  The best way to do that would be to type `dput(Data3)` into your console, then copy and paste the output of that into the body of your question, formatted as code.  The output will look something like `structure(... `.  This way, we can copy and paste that code block to reproduce your dataset and help you out.

Comment: Also, what are you getting now with the above code?  Do you get any plot at all or just a blank screen?  Any error messages or warnings?

Comment: added the format you have wanted. I tried to write it myself. so it's not great, but I get some plots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the meaning of your features, but did you think about something like this?

```
Data2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Name, y = value)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = test), alpha = 0.5, position = "jitter")
```

Comment: Thank yo9u. Thisis much better and I'll build on this :)